# Elegant way to combine two state-changing functions?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make something similar to `combineReducers` from Redux in Scala, when each function controls its small part of state but can't figure out an elegant way to make it type safe. So far I have something like this which doesn't look good at all.

```
sealed trait Event

case class Create() extends Event
case class Save() extends Event

object Reducers {
  type IntState = Int
  type StringState = String

  def intReducer(e: Event, state: IntState): IntState = ???

  def stringReducer(e: Event, state: StringState): StringState = ???

  def combineReducers[E, S1, S2](f: (E, S1) => S1, g: (E, S2) => S2): (E, (S1, S2)) => (S1, S2) = {
    { (e: E, states: (S1, S2)) => (f(e, states._1), g(e, states._2)) }
  }

  def combineReducers2[E, S1, S2, S3](f: (E, (S1, S2)) => (S1, S2), g: (E, S3) => S3): (E, (S1, S2, S3)) => (S1, S2, S3) = ???
}
```

It seems that shapeless records are a good fit, though being new to type-heavy programming I can't figure out the type of what should work along the lines the following (or maybe it should take a tagged HList of functions?)

```
def combineReducers(fTag: String, f: (E,A) => A, gTag: String, g: (E,B) => B): (E, HList1) => HList2 = {
  { (e: E, state: HList3) =>
    (fTag ->> f(e, state(fTag)) :: (gTag ->> g(e, state(gTag)) :: HNil
  }
}
```

Comment: Say hello to the [state monad](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html).

Comment: @erip I don't see how the state monad will be useful here. My problem is that the shape of the state changes with each function added to the reducer.

Comment: 1) don't have two states -- combine them into a single composite state. 2) In my experience, it's rarely useful to use primitives as state. You'll at least want to wrap them in an ADT. Combing this with state monad should solve your problems unless I'm still misunderstanding.

Comment: @erip the goal is combine arbitrary number of "reducer" functions with as few lines of boilerplate code as possible.

Comment: Oh, I think I see the issue: is it that these reducers dynamically add components to the state? For example, one reducer might add the username; one reducer might add the gravatar? The state's "shape" isn't known a priori? Sorry if this is wrong, I'm not familiar with redux. If this is so, I don't know if there's necessarily a way to do this with a strong type system. There are an infinite number of types with an infinite number of ways to map between them.

Comment: It looks like you could use shapeless to build an HList with the types introduced by each reducer combine step.

Comment: @Bilk, yeah, I'm trying to use shapeless records but can't figure out the type signature for `combineReducers` function

Comment: Btw, state Monad is `S => (A, S)`. The type here is `(A, S) => S`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go, was fun trying to figure out what may be the correct typeclass :D

```
import cats._
import cats.implicits._

sealed trait Event
case class Create() extends Event
case class Save() extends Event

type Reducer[A] = (Event, A) => A

val intReducer: Reducer[Int] = ???
val stringReducer: Reducer[String] = ???
val doubleReducer: Reducer[Double] = ???

implicit object ReducerIS extends InvariantSemigroupal[Reducer] {
  override def product[A, B](fa: Reducer[A], fb: Reducer[B]): Reducer[(A, B)] =
    (e: Event, ab:(A,B)) => (fa(e,ab._1), fb(e, ab._2))
  override def imap[A, B](fa: Reducer[A])(f: A => B)(g: B => A): Reducer[B] = (e, b) => f(fa(e, g(b)))
}

val combined: Reducer[(Int, String, Double)] = (intReducer, stringReducer, doubleReducer).tupled
```

My implementation for `InvariantSemigroupal` isn't very clean, but really the types force you throughout, hard to get it wrong.

The `.tupled` method is implicit from cats, and requires an implicit `InvariantSemigroupal` for `Reducer` in our case

Comment: Do you mind looking at updated question? I'm trying to figure out a type signature to use shapeless tagged HLists as a state.

Comment: I think my answer is a valid one for your original question, you can raise a new so question for your second question :)

Comment: Also, I see no reason for using HList for your problem, you can do what you need with cats as shown

Comment: I should've asked about actual task at hand ) which is to combine an arbitrary number of such functions. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52724750/using-shapeless-records-to-combine-arbitrary-number-of-state-changing-functions